# php7.4-fpm doesn't work with nginx/1.21.3

Tags: nginx

I have an experimental setup of manually compiled **nginx/1.21.3** w http3 + quic.

I have also successfully compiled an experimental **curl** w http3 implementation:

```
root@domac:~# curl --version
curl 7.80.0-DEV (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.80.0-DEV OpenSSL/1.1.1k zlib/1.2.11 ngtcp2/0.1.0-DEV nghttp3/0.1.0-DEV
Release-Date: [unreleased]
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS HSTS HTTP3 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
root@domac:~#
```

However, when I download https://domac.alu.hr:8443/test.php, i receive this:

```
mtodorov@domac:~$ curl --http3 https://domac.alu.hr:8443/test.php
<?php var_export($_SERVER)?>
mtodorov@domac:~$
```

My nginx is:

```
root@domac:~# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.21.3 (nginx-quic)
built by gcc 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1 (compatible; BoringSSL) (running with BoringSSL)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --build=nginx-quic --with-debug --add-module=../njs/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx --user=www-data --group=www-data --with-threads --with-file-aio --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_v3_module --with-http_quic_module --with-stream_quic_module --with-cc-opt=-I../boringssl/include --with-ld-opt='-L../boringssl/build/ssl -L../boringssl/build/crypto'
root@domac:~#
```

My /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;
pid        /var/run/nginx/nginx.pid;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    index         index.php index.html index.htm;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  domac.alu.hr;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        root   /srv/www/nginx;

        location / {
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            # root           /srv/www/nginx;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            # if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                # return 404;
            # }

            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  HTTP_PROXY "";
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #

      server {
            listen 8443 ssl;              # TCP listener for HTTP/1.1
            listen 8443 http3 reuseport;  # UDP listener for QUIC+HTTP/3

            ssl_protocols       TLSv1.3; # QUIC requires TLS 1.3
            ssl_certificate     certs/domac_alu_hr_20201111.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key certs/private/domac_alu_hr_20201111.key;

            add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":8443"';   # Advertise that HTTP/3 is available
            add_header QUIC-Status $quic;     # Sent when QUIC was used

            root   /srv/www/nginx;

            location / {
            }

            access_log  /var/log/nginx/access-ssl.log  main;
            error_log   /var/log/nginx/error-ssl.log   info;
      }

    # server {
    #     listen       8443 ssl http3 quic;
    #     server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    # }

}
```

The problem seems to be that php7.4-fpm is not called, but nginx displays verbatim test.php file, instead of the result of its run?

On the same server, there is an apache2 daemon that works well with php7.4-fpm and HTTP/2, but I wanted to implement HTTP/3, which is currently (October 01st 2021) not supported by apache2 AFAIK.

Thank you very much, I have even tried to `strace -p <proc>` on the master nginx proc, but it doesn't seem to even try to open the **/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock** ...

I know this is an experimental build, but I would like to make it work.
I thought of fastcgi support might have been compiled out, but such ./configure option was not turned on.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the server block which listens on port 8443 (where you accessing it from), there is no PHP handler configured. Obviously, you should add it for PHP-FPM to process scripts.

Copy `location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) { .. }` over to within `server { }` with 8443 port.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this. It's a stupid omission. Thanks.

Comment: Later I saw that I wasn't so stupid, all the answers on the web had the PHP enabled within the port 80 configuration and I have just copied it. But   I am a nginx newbie.